# Option Nuget Deploy doesn't appear on the Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm trying to create a Nuget Package from a project on Visual Studio 2015, but the option "Nuget Deploy" doesn't appear on the options of the menu

[Image of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbwmE.jpg)

The option I'm trying to find, is this one, shown in the image below

[Image of the project that appears the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqULI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to install the Nuget Deploy extension.

On Visual Studio, click on Tools > Extensions and Updates...

Search Online for the "Nuget Deploy" extension

[Image of Nuget Deploy extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwhtT.jpg)

And download it.